# The most efficient way to do the differences between the columns in SAS

Tags: sas, diff

I have a SAS data set like below. I want to use the first column values as a minuend, which is column 2 - column 1, column 3 - column 1, column 4 - column 1... Which is the most efficient way to do this diff in SAS? Using array or do loop?

```
hotelID   expense1  expense2  expense3  expense4  expense5
1         41241     56234     45124     12551     74245
2         31232     45213     51411     67432     23523
3         75463     14352     74214     51541     25236
4         95324     21451     73423     15215     56432
5         12445     64622     12156     52442     52351
6         43542     24141     62532     63255     78454
7         12625     14525     45235     15351     15364
```

Comment: To find the most efficient (CPU time?) you might want to try different approaches and determine it empirically. Perhaps do loop (looping over an array) vs 4 assignment statements vs transposing to normalized format and using BY-group processing to retain first.expense as the minuend.

Comment: With such a simple calculation I suspect disk I/O rather than CPU will be the limiting factor, so the choice of method is unlikely to make much of a difference assuming that it's all running within one data step. I'd go with the array option mainly for the sake of having tidy code.

Comment: @user667489, can you give me the code how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `arrays` like below

```
data _NULL_;
set test;
array all{*} expense2-expense5;
array diff{*} diff_exp2-diff_exp5;
do i=1 to dim(all);
diff[i]= expense1 - all{i};
end;
put _ALL_;
run;
```